# how to make mesh faces look smooth?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

I am a amateur to Blender but I want to make a model for my sims game. However, I want to know how I can make faces smooth? As in not have them look blockish / crinkly... if that makes sense. I need a smooth interior and exterior (excluding the shelves). I tried subdivsion surface but that just makes the mesh look all doughy... anyways, thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: @moonboots THANK YOU IT WORKED!!! :)!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click to access to *Object Context Menu* and *Shade Smooth* (or header menu > *Object > Shade Smooth*). You can change the angle threshold of smoothness in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth*. But the whole shape will still look angulous on its borders, if you need to round it for real you need to give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (and apply it if you want to import into a game engine).

Comment: yes you're right, it looks like it has to do with a keyboard setting I've imported, I don't know why it removes these settings though...